# Is plexydesk supported on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (Trusty)

Tags: ppa

I tried installing but it fails.

```
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/plexydesk/plexydesk-dailybuild/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I read on [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+question/257202) that it is not supported.

Hope someone can help me install it.

Comment: It doesn't look like the project is still active. The last packages in the ppa are from 2012, there are no packages for Trusty there, hence, nothing to install.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/~plexydesk/+archive/ubuntu/plexydesk/+packages) as well as the the [official website](http://www.plexydesk.org/download/) it is only available for 15.04, 15.10 and 16.04 version of Ubuntu.

Yet you might be able to make use of its source code which is still unstable but available [here](https://github.com/plexydesk/plexydesk/releases/tag/v1.0.1).

Answer (score -1):

For updated builds please check https://launchpad.net/~plexydesk/+archive/ubuntu/plexydesk

for https://launchpad.net/~plexydesk for other builds.

Comment: This is not a useful answer. What is in the link, is for 15.04, 15.10 and 16.04. There is nothing related to 14.04.